# How to manually deserialize an SOAP response with WS-Address

Tags: c#, soap, xml-deserialization

I need to parse an XML document as return value for a webservice which is currently offline. So I want to create a façade while I wait for it's availability. This is a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <env:Header>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:AD90B9C079ED11E3BF6E3900E216CC13</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:ReplyTo>
         <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
         <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
            <instra:tracking.ecid xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">cd42df45b193f389:55338234:143243fa919:-8000-0000000000432eda</instra:tracking.ecid>
         </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
      </wsa:ReplyTo>
      <wsa:FaultTo>
         <wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
         <wsa:ReferenceParameters>
            <instra:tracking.ecid xmlns:instra="http://xmlns.oracle.com/sca/tracking/1.0">cd42df45b193f389:55338234:143243fa919:-8000-0000000000432eda</instra:tracking.ecid>
         </wsa:ReferenceParameters>
      </wsa:FaultTo>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <db:BancosDbOutput xmlns:db="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/recuperaBancosDb">
         <db:recuperaBancosDbOutput>
            <db:nomeBanco>BANCO ABC BRASIL S.A.</db:nomeBanco>
            <db:numeroBanco>246</db:numeroBanco>
            <db:pais>Brasil</db:pais>
         </db:recuperaBancosDbOutput>
         <db:recuperaBancosDbOutput>
            <db:nomeBanco>BANCO A.J.RENNER S.A.</db:nomeBanco>
            <db:numeroBanco>654</db:numeroBanco>
            <db:pais>Brasil</db:pais>
         </db:recuperaBancosDbOutput>
      </db:BancosDbOutput>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I got this service WSDL and XSD files and I generated the proxies with `WSDL.exe`, but I'm unable to deserialize this response to that webservice proxy objects. I usually get a `SerializationException: Parse Error, no assembly associated with Xml key` when i try something like this:

```
private bool SOAPDeserialize<T>(string filePath, out T ClassObj)
{
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        try
        {
            SoapFormatter soap = new SoapFormatter();
            soap.AssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
            ClassObj = (T) soap.Deserialize(fs);
        }
        catch (SerializationException ex)
        {
            ClassObj = default(T);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Do you have any leads on how this can be done?

Comment: Have you references the assembly that provides an association with `BancosDbOutput`?

Comment: I got the classes generated by WSDL.exe; I don't have access to webservice assembly itself